# RAII way to choose between two constructors

Tags: c++, constructor, raii

I have a class that holds a large table of data, with a constructor that takes all of the parameters needed to calculate that data. However, it takes a long time to run, so I've added a constructor that takes a stream, and reads the data in from that stream. I'm having trouble coming up with a RAII way of designing this class though, since I have two constructors, and at run time I need to choose between them. This is what I've come up with:

```
std::string filename; // Populated by command line arguments
DataTable table; // Empty constructor, no resource acquisition or initialization

if( filename.empty() ) {
    table = DataTable(/*various parameters*/);
} else {
    std::ifstream filestream(filename);

    table = DataTable(filestream); // Reads from file
}
```

That looks pretty fragile to me. The default constructor will leave the object in a valid state, but a useless one. The only use of it is to create a "temporary" object in the outer scope, to be assigned to in one of the branches of the if statement. Additionally, there's a flag "inited" behind the scenes to manage if the object was default-constructed or fully initialized. Is there a better way to design this class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
DataTable foo = filename.empty()
              ? DataTable(x, y, z)
              : DataTable(std::ifstream(filename));
```

Comment: That's the right approach.  He'll probably want to add a move constructor if he does so, and of course, that will only work if he has C++11.  (And he won't be able to bind the temporary `ifstream` to an `std::istream&`; he'll need to use something like `std::ifstream(filename).seekg( 0, std::ios_base::beg )`.  Or have the constructor take an rvalue reference, again, if he has C++11.)

Answer (score 0):

Move the file test code that decides which way to init into the ctor, move the ctors into two private `init` functions, call one of these from the ctor or throw an exception if everything fails.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

1. Get rid of the "inited" flag.
2. Get rid of the default constructor if it can't sensibly construct the object
3. use this kind of construct to get you a `DataTable`:

   ```
   DataTable get_me_my_data_fool(ParameterTypes... params, const string& filename = "")
   {
     if(!filename.empty())
       return DataTable(std::ifstream(filename)); // check if file exists!
     else  
       return DataTable(params...);
   }
   ```

Actually, now that I think about it, it would be better to just put this logic into the `DataTable` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If the class supports copy, then Kerrek SB's solution is the way
to go.  From what you say, however, copying is expensive.  In
that case, and you can use C++11, you might try adding a move
constructor, in order to avoid the deep copy.  Otherwise, you're
probably stuck allocating dynamically:

```
std::auto_ptr<DataTable> fooPtr( filename.empty()
                                 ? new DataTable( x, y z )
                                 : new DataTable( filename ) );
DataTable& foo = *fooPtr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another idea for completeness sake:

```
template<typename T>
class uninitialised
{
public:
    ~uninitialised()
    {
        if (alive_) {
            operator T&().~T();
        }
    }

    template<typename... Ts>
    void create(Ts&&... args)
    {
        assert(!alive_ && "create must only be called once");
        void* const p = obj_;
        ::new(p) T(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
        alive_ = true;
    }

    operator T&()
    {
        assert(alive_ && "T has not been created yet");
        return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(obj_);
    }

private:
    bool alive_ = false;
    alignas(T) unsigned char obj_[sizeof(T)];
};

// ...

std::string filename;
uninitialised<DataTable> table;

if (filename.empty()) {
    table.create(/* various parameters */);
} else {
    std::ifstream filestream(filename);
    table.create(filestream);
}

DataTable& tbl = table;
```